# What's the sense of "relative prestige" in Français ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais

I'm reading an article with sustained English so I don't get everything.
To quote the article :

> They show that humans, unlike chimpanzees, use “relative prestige” to assign status, and then use that status as a signal of what to believe and emulate.

What does "relative prestige" mean in this example? I've made my own research on linguee but it looks like there's no real traduction.

Comment: Je doute qu'il y ait une seule traduction avec un mot composé, mais plutôt une paraphrase. Il s'agit d'une hiérarchie où tous les animaux ont un statut ou un rang social relatif aux autres. La notion de « prestige » ici ne signifie que « position dans l'hiérarchie ».

Comment: You could maybe use "position hiérarchique relative"... since it's quoted in the original text, you could also use "prestige relatif", as it's an invented concept anyway (in the original text I mean)

Comment: @LukeSawczak the thing about chimpanzees lost me I think.. Like we all know their system.

Comment: This seems to me to be a techical term in sociology or ethology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it is written, it isn't about the French language. In any case, both *relative*  and *prestige* perfectly match their French siblings *relatif* and *prestige*.

Comment: It perfectly matches relatif and prestige but it has no sense if you traduce them literally :) @jlliagre

Comment: Mieux vaut continuer en français plutôt que continuer à massacrer la langue anglaise... Est-ce que tu comprends la signification de l'expression *ils sont classés en fonction de leurs mérites respectifs* ?

Comment: @jlliagre pas du tout, "mérites respectifs" ça ne veut rien dire comme ça, ça voudrais dire le mérite de chacun, qui permettrait d'assigner les status.
C'est à dire ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu ne comprends pas ? **Mérite** ? : *Caractère de celui qui est digne d'une appréciation avantageuse par ses qualités morales ou intellectuelles.* **Respectif** ? : *Qui concerne, revient ou appartient à chacun des éléments pris en compte dans l'ensemble considéré.* **Prestige** ? *Fait d'imposer le respect, d'inspirer l'admiration, de séduire, de faire forte impression.* **Relatif** ? *Qui devrait être comparé avec la moyenne des notions, des choses ou des êtres de même espèce* **Statut** (avec un t) ? : *Situation d'un individu ou d'une catégorie d'individus dans un groupe.*

Answer (score 1):

I am neither a specialist of [sociolinguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics)), nor a French native but still I will give a try.
Below it is my attempt to translate the original sentence (based on feedback received and following the spirit of @jlliagre's answer).

> They show that humans, unlike chimpanzees, use “relative prestige” to
>   assign status, and then use that status as a signal of what to believe
>   and emulate.
>
> Ils (les chercheurs) montrent que les humains, contrairement aux chimpanzés, utilisent le "prestige relatif" pour attribuer un statut, et puis ils (les humains) utilisent ce statut comme un signal de ce qu'il faut croire et imiter.

Prestige has the same figurative connotation in French and English according to my understanding.

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prestige

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prestige

Here are two books using prestige relatif. I have not verified if the authors come from the Hexagone.

[Les théories de la fécondité](https://books.google.ro/books?id=bd68BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=prestige%20relatif&source=bl&ots=90LG6XTLLa&sig=xuW3RTPppf6FrfG7OkhIl1O3bLM&hl=el&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ5PKWyMffAhVSrxoKHWx1DOYQ6AEwC3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=prestige%20relatif&f=false)

[Les réseaux criminels](https://books.google.ro/books?id=xY89DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT231&lpg=PT231&dq=prestige%20relatif&source=bl&ots=HjD3D778gi&sig=AxzO_qNfJDdaWiGkRsvO2Ltr4y0&hl=el&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ5PKWyMffAhVSrxoKHWx1DOYQ6AEwDHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=prestige%20relatif&f=false)

Here is the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prestige%20relatif&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprestige%20relatif%3B%2Cc0) of prestige relatif.

I think that, based on @Nathan and @Luke Sawczak comments, one may also use "position hiérarchique relative" and "position dans la hiérarchie", as alternatives.

Comment: There are several issues with your translation attempt...

Comment: @jlliagre I just attempted to answer an old unanswered question.

Comment: @jlliagre I would appreciate any advice in order to improve my translation.

Comment: What is the subject of *utilisent*?

Comment: @jlliagre You are right. I modified my answer. Thanks in advance for any further feedback.

Comment: *Il montrent qu'aux humains...* is wrong. It means "They show that to the humans...". Who *ceux-là* is referring to?

Comment: @jlliagre Another attempt:-)! Still thank you very much for your invaluable comments.

Comment: @Montéedelait I edited my answer. Thanks for your useful comment

Comment: Your translation is okay now. How do you know *ils* are *les chercheurs*? ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre See edit:-)! Merci for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the question, despite being off topic in my opinion.

> They show that humans, unlike chimpanzees, use “relative prestige” to assign status, and then use that status as a signal of what to believe and emulate.

means:

> Ils (les chercheurs) montrent que les êtres humains, contrairement aux chimpanzés, s'appuient sur le « prestige relatif » des individus pour les hiérarchiser. Le statut qui en résulte indique qui croire et de qui s'inspirer.

As an example of such difference between humans and chimpanzees, Stephen Hawking had a very high prestige and was trusted as a model in his domain for the most of us while chimpanzees classify themselves not according to prestige, but to physical dominance, fitness, ability to bring back food.

See [The evolution of prestige](http://radicalanthropologygroup.org/sites/default/files/pdf/class_text_065.pdf), by Joseph Henrich and Francisco J. Gil-White